# How to work with very small float numbers in python3 (e.g. 8.5e-350)

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, precision

Is there some type like long in Python 2 that can handle very small number like 8.5e-350?
Or is there any way around in this situation because python supresses floats after 320 decimal places to 0?

Comment: You can use a 3rd party library like [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org).

Comment: Python doesn't: ieee format does

Comment: Just for curiosity, why do you want to manipulate such small values? that's way, way smaller than Planck's length, I can't think of any application where it'd make sense to manipulate something so small.

Answer (score 1):

The standard library comes with [the decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal)

> > The decimal module provides support for fast correctly-rounded decimal
> >     floating point arithmetic. It offers several advantages over the float
> >     datatype.
>
> ...
>
> > Unlike hardware based binary floating point, the decimal module has a user alterable precision (defaulting to 28 places) which can be as
> >     large as needed for a given problem:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 500
>>> Decimal(10) / Decimal(3)
Decimal('3.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333')
>>> len('3.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333')
501
```

[Quick start tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Python uses IEEE 745 so you don't get 350 decimal places, you get about 15 significant figures and a limit on the exponent to +/-350.   If that number of significant figures is OK, and you don't need more dynamic range (i.e. all your values are small), express your quantities in different units so your values are in a suitable range.